# Is it possible to completely and safely remove Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: 11.10, dual-boot, uninstall

I have got Windows XP and by dual-boot method installed Ubuntu 11.10.

I do not want, to un install Ubuntu, but I'm interested.

Is it possible to completely and safely un-install Ubuntu from dual-boot, and recover all the hard disk space, that Ubuntu has stolen from Windows? And may I, when I'll want it, reinstall it again ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yep, you can do that, even though I'm not sure about the "remotely" part. Use Windows XP's disk management tool to first delete the partition, then restore the bootloader using the Windows xp install disk, boot to it, select the option to run a terminal, then run `fixboot` and `fixmbr`.

Comment: Specifically: The "Recovery Console" on the XP installation media

Comment: Yes, and "Command Prompt" on Windows 7 installation media. Thanks, I forgot about that.